# Editing Particular line in an Excel(CSV) using c++

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a transaction manager using c++.

I have one CSV file containing all the customer details along with bank account
I in order to update the bank balance after a transaction need to access one particular line and change the bank balance.

My CSV Entry is in the form NAME,USN(Identification Code),Bank Balance

I found a piece of code on how to jump to a line on stack by @DanielTuzes as follows

```
#include <fstream>
#include <limits>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;



fstream& Go2Line(fstream& file, unsigned int num)
{
    file.seekg(ios::beg);
    for(unsigned int i=0; i < num - 1; ++i)
        file.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(),'\n');

    return file;
}



int main()
{
    fstream file("/media/LOGGING/darsv1.csv",ios_base::in);
    if (!file)
        cout << "Unable to open file /media/LOGGING/darsv1.csv\n";
    else 
    {
        int Number2Go = 4;
        Go2Line(file, Number2Go);

        if (!file)
            cout << "Unable to reach line " << Number2Go << ".\n";
        else
        {
            string line;
            getline(file,line);
            cout << "Line " << Number2Go << "reached successfully. It is:\n" << line;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Can someone Please help in updating the excel(csv) file.

EDIT:
I am not able to find how to change the line I get from the above Code and put it back in the excel file.

Comment: You cannot change the line in place. I'd recommend to crate a `std::vector` reading all the lines, modify the data and write it back after.

Comment: Unless the new contents of the line have the same exact number of characters as the existing contents, the file cannot be edited in place. You must read in the entire contents of the file, and the create a new file or rewrite the existing file, with the updated contents.

Comment: okay assuming they are of same number of characters how to do it?